# Do we need sharepoint to be installed on same machine for developement?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am writing a small program to connect sharepoint then retrieving document from it using C#.
Can anyone suggest me APIs to access sharepoint (2007).

1. Do i need to setup sharepoint on my machine? If yes then is there any alternative to do so?
2. I am also looking for some sample code to start with coding?
3. Is it compulsory to code on Windows Server OS ?

Jene

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you are accessing SharePoint using the Object Model then yes you need to run the code in the SharePoint server/Web Front End Farm for the code to work.
2. One alternate is that you can use the Web Services provided by SharePoint to access the details from SharePoint, this method will not require you to run the code in the SharePoint server.
   You can find this [example](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/archive/2009/01/06/getting-started-with-sharepoint-wss-web-services-using-linq-to-xml.aspx) for accessing the SharePoint using WS
3. No you can develop your code in the non Server OS and test it in the Server OS, if you want to debug they you will have to develop it in the server OS where the SharePoint is installed / you will have to use the remote debugger. Note : SharePoint 2010 allows you to have a development setup in Windows 7 OS.

Comment: can u suggest me some APIs for it ? and link providing information about that dll ?

Comment: Not quite correct on point #3 - you can use Visual Studio Remote Debugger

Comment: SharePoint (WSS) SDK is here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms441339.aspx there are thousands of tutorials on on web and hundreds on stack overflow.

Comment: I'd just like to make the point that it's (IMO, of course) just so much easier to do your SharePoint development in VMware or some other virtualized environment.  Performance is acceptable on a decent dev workstation, and you have the added benefit of VM snapshots which are occasionally useful to roll back horrible configuration or deployment mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have Sharepoint installed on my localmachine, I use WSSDeploy to do all that, that way, all i need to do is add the references to the correct DLLS for sharepoint in my project and can code as normal.

[WSSDeploy http://wssdeploy.codeplex.com/](http://wssdeploy.codeplex.com/)